# How can I explore EF relationships and models at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model call "Customer" which is to be linked to several other models (tables) in Entity Framework. When deleting the said Customer, I need to show all the related records and their counts and finally list all the records before allowing the user to delete the customer.

For example I might say this Customer is related to : Orders (1), Order_Items (5) where a customer is directly linked to an Order, and then an Order is linked to Order Items, but deleting the Customer will impact records in both the tables.

Is there a way to do this in .net dynamically or will I need to have a static view where I update all this info every time I make changes to the model and relationships?

Comment: It's possible, but hard due to counterintuitive overcomplicated EF6 metadata model. And due to overencapsulation many useful information is hidden in internal classes/members. If's much easier in EF Core. Good luck.

Comment: oh thanks. Do you have a link to the EF Core example?